# Privacy of Hyperledger composer rest server

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

In Hyperledger composer rest api (composer-rest-server) are secure with [Enabling authentication for the REST server](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/integrating/enabling-rest-authentication). but in http://localhost:3000/explorer, All sensitive data is not encryption. Could i use cryptography or other approach to encrypt and decrypt like Zero Knowledge Proof to prevent data privacy (sensitive data)?
And I see [Securing the REST server using HTTPS and TLS](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/integrating/securing-the-rest-server), when i run command `composer-rest-server -c alice1@my-network -t` and then open browser `https://localhost:3000/explorer`, but I don't know how to use it?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you would use TLS between the REST client and REST server - see https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/integrating/securing-the-rest-server and general/useful info on TLS with diagrams [here](https://devcentral.f5.com/articles/ssl-profiles-part-8-client-authentication)

You would really need to set up authentication (known user identities that are using it) with TLS like discussed [here](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/integrating/enabling-rest-authentication) then connect to the authentication path for your application to authenticate the user using the REST APIs https://localhost:3000/auth/github: ((or whatever the authPath is for your implemented strategy)) and then interactions/ data in transit between client and server will be encrypted.

Once the REST server is up and running and TLS enabled - you will authenticate at your REST client as the user in question: once authenticated, that user gets an access token or similar. In terms of Composer and the deployed business network / smart contract - that user will (already) have been issued a business network card - that includes the user's blockchain identity (key/cert) and contain connection info/metadata (ie how to connect to the deployed/runtime business network out on the Fabric network). This access may be programmatically, from an application client that's using REST APIs (ie the app user that's logged in to the app, has been assigned this business network card) or indeed - a user is using the REST API client in a browser for example (eg.  he/she would import it into their Wallet in the REST client then that would be the default identity in the REST API session, and which interacts / signs transactions that update the business network (create asset, update asset etc), as REST API operations to the REST Server (over TLS) that interacts with the Fabric network (over TLS).

Comment: I've noticed that the userId value which is used for identifying the user throughout the code is the same value as set in the userId cookie. Does it mean that, knowing that value for some other user, I can signin as that user, just setting that cookie value manually?

Comment: a user that's authenticated gets a token intended for 'him'. He then uses a business network card (which contains a blockchain identity (certificate/key) to interact as a blockchain participant on that business network (deployed smart contract). If another user - from the browser or client - then you would normally authenticate that user (however the Google OAUTH2 example is using 'client' authentication, as opposed to 'user' authentication - you shouldn't confuse the two).